# Secret message on my friend's computer's screen

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

My friend suddenly left the office today.
He left his computer on carelessly.
On the screen, I can see a message.

The message on the screen:

> Counts n, key at, old er, handphon
>  A, secret m, you se,
>  So i,
>   puzzling u,
>  Go on, great and, powerful on, the go,
>
> Dear u, 
>  Do a, greater and, big x,
>   Not to, brings co,
>   Secret ly, coming for, important x,

I think he is a secret agent.
He got important message.
What is the message ?
Where is he going ?

Comment: Is handphon intended to be handphone as in mobile phone/cellphone or is the lack of the e intentional?

Comment: @jamesCoyle Handphone is Cellphone. The lack of e is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the answer for my puzzle :**

The clues from the messages

> count n  => counts the leters in each word
>  older handphone => check old handpone keypad
>  coma after each 2 words => each 2 words for a letter

After counting the letters to each words, we get:

> 61 32 32 81   61 32 21 81 22 53 82 32  41 21 73 31 32 62 62 63 91

mapping the handphone keypad to letters we get :

> [image]
>  21 => a, 22 => b, 23 => c, 31 => d, 32=> e and so on

the secret message is

> "meet me at blue garden now".
>  So he is going to the blue garden.

Comment: You could have added a hint instead of self answering.

Comment: The disjointed and misspelled manner of the message, although central to the puzzle, made it difficult to parse into something meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

**A Partial Answer:**

I'm rather new to puzzling, so these are some of the first things that popped into my head:

When sorted by comma, the sets of words grouped together creat this:

> n at er A m se i u on and on go u a and x to co ly for x
>
> Counts key old handphon secret you so puzzling go great powerful the dear do greater big not brings secret coming important

I tried ceaser cyphering the first grouping, but no luck

When sorting the second words alphabetically I get this

> A a and and at co er for go i ly m n on on se to u u x x
>
> handphon
> do great greater key brings old coming the so secret secret counts go powerful you not puzzling dear big important

When sorting the first words alphabetically I get this:

> x co for n u a and and on A c at to er on u ly m i go se
>
> big brings coming counts dear do great greater go handphon important key not old powerful puzzling secret secret so the you

A couple of interesting things I noted:

> There are 36 clauses (A nice perfect square)
>
> secret is the only word repeated in the first "section" of the clause
>
> a, and, on, u, and x, are all repeated in the second "section" of the clause
>
> handphon is the only non-word in the first "section" of the clause, the only clause with a capital second "section", and the only clause separated by a line break. I have a feeling this is a big part of the riddle.
>
> there are 21 clauses total. 12 in the first paragraph, and 9 in the second

Those are my observations! Hopefully someone with more expierence than I can do something with them

Comment: Your answer is wrong, but because you are the only one answering my puzzle, so you get the bounty prize.